# cannot compile moses(undefined reference to boost:: ...)

Tags: c++, boost, moses

I am trying to compile moses(machine translation tool).
I specified the location of boost when compiling as follows.

```
./bjam --with-boost=/home/xhotsuki/bin/boost_1_56_0 -j8
```

But I got many errors something like this.

```
...failed gcc.link mert/bin/gcc-4.4.6/release/debug-symbols-on/link-static/threading-multi/timer_test...
...skipped <pmert/bin/gcc-4.4.6/release/debug-symbols-on/link-static/threading-multi>timer_test.passed for lack of <pmert/bin/gcc-4.4.6/release/debug-symbols-on/link-static/threading-multi>timer_test...
gcc.link mert/bin/gcc-4.4.6/release/debug-symbols-on/link-static/threading-multi/util_test
mert/bin/gcc-4.4.6/release/debug-symbols-on/link-static/threading-multi/UtilTest.o: In function 'main':<br>
/home/xhotsuki/bin/boost_1_56_0/include/boost/test/unit_test.hpp:59: undefined reference to `boost::unit_test::unit_test_main(bool (*)(), int, char**)'
```

What has gone wrong?

Comment: Have u solved this issue?

Comment: sorry but i haven't solved this issue.

Comment: I solved this issue and I create a docker hub image to help others use moses server without worrying about installation of it.
https://hub.docker.com/repository/docker/alaahamoudah/dockerized_moses_server

Answer (score 0):

My colleague and I have created a docker image to help in installation of moses server with all its dependencies, it is taking some time to build but it succeed at the end and you can only worry about using it and deploy your models.

https://hub.docker.com/repository/docker/alaahamoudah/dockerized_moses_server